# Motion not available ios 17 live photo

Tags: ios, swift, ios17, phlivephoto

Does anyone have any ideas on how to work with a new ios 17 live photo? I can save the live photo, but I can’t set it as wallpaper. Error is "motion not available ios 17 swift".
I use [Live photo](https://github.com/LimitPoint/LivePhoto) library.

Also, I changed the metadata for different keys and didn't get a positive result.

```
    let addone = addSampleTime()
    lett addtwo = addSampleTime2()
    let addthree = addLiveTime()
    let Allmediatimed = "3 0.00823200028389692 16939217 155 5.94521753062658e-15 -6.44374300689783e-15 0.27380958199501 0.575768828392029 1.92900002002716 3.30649042129517 4 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9.80908925027372e-45 -0.17872442305088 3212927435 33811 49646"
    assetWriter?.metadata = [addone, addtwo, addthree]
    
    private func addSampleTime()->AVMetadataItem {
    let item = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    let keyContentIdentifier = "Sample Time" quickTimeMetadataKeyContentIdentifier
    let keySpaceQuickTimeMetadata = "mdta"
    item.key = keyContentIdentifier as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    item.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: keySpaceQuickTimeMetadata)
    item.value = "0 s" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    item.dataType = "com.apple.metadata.datatype.UTF-8"
    return item
    }
    
    private func addSampleTime2()->AVMetadataItem {
    let item = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    let keyContentIdentifier = "Sample Duration" quickTimeMetadataKeyContentIdentifier
    let keySpaceQuickTimeMetadata = "mdta"
    item.key = keyContentIdentifier as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    item.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: keySpaceQuickTimeMetadata)
    item.value = "0.03 s" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    item.dataType = "com.apple.metadata.datatype.UTF-8"
    return item
    }
    
    private func addLiveTime()->AVMetadataItem {
    let item = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    let keyContentIdentifier = "Live Photo Info"  quickTimeMetadataKeyContentIdentifier
    let keySpaceQuickTimeMetadata = "mdta"
    item.key = keyContentIdentifier as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    item.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: keySpaceQuickTimeMetadata)
    item.value = self.Allmediatimed as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    item.dataType = "com.apple.metadata.datatype.UTF-8"
    return item
    }
```

Comment: Q: Same code, iOS 16 works? What about getting LivePhoto via Apple API, like `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller` ?

Comment: Live wallpapers added to ios 17 with modified live photos. I just need to create live photo from video and picture. With the ability to set them as live wallpaper. Without using the camera.

Comment: Yeah, but if it isn't taking assets created by the library you are using, you need to get at least one example of the real thing to test and compare.

Comment: I should add, I saw one YT reviewer (for iPadOS 17) saying that he had lots of problems with older live photos, but all the new LivePhotos he took in iOS 17 (on device) worked.

Comment: I use this approach in ios 17. I successfully create live photos, but they are not set as live wallpaper.
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
      let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
      request.addResource(with: .photo, fileURL: imageUrl, options: nil)
      request.addResource(with: .pairedVideo, fileURL: videoUrl, options: nil)
    } completionHandler: { success, _ in
      completion(success)
    }

Comment: We must find how heic is formated and the relations to video. Even if you remove atom part and boxed info from movie it will work. So the focus must be on understanting relations in heic file related to movie frames.

Comment: Hi @MarekRoslik, Have you found the solution of live photo. Live Photo not working as a wallpaper. I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Tajindersingh Still haven't found any solution

Comment: Okay , Thanks for the reply @MarekRoslik

Comment: `https://github.com/chris01b/LivePhotoWallpaper/` i have tested this code and it works.Still need to figure out few things but this will solve the motion problem you are having.